# Nested Query blues...grouping by nested object

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

My `Object` has many `transactions` which belong to a `type`, whcich then belong to a `group`. I would like to pull all the transactions from my `Object` which are in a specific group, say `blue`.

Been trying to do this using both SQL and Activerecord and have failed in both endeavors.

I can get this procedure to print out the quality by which I then want to sort by:

```
object.transactions.map { |to| "#{to.transaction_type.transaction_group.name}" }
```

And here is a sample of what i have been running, but oviously dosen't work. Haven't managed to find a way to

```
id = Group.find_by_name("name")
object.transactions.where(transaction_type.group_id == id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you do something like:

```
id = Group.find_by_name("name")
object.transactions.
  joins(:type).
  where("types.group_id" => id)
```

Comment: has to be `joins(:type)` or it gives me an error becuase the transaction -belongs to- a type and dosent -have many- types

Comment: Tried this and it tells me that operator does not exist: `pv.transactions.joins(:transaction_type).where('transaction_types.transaction_group_id == ?', 7)` @cheeseweasel

Comment: Got it! @cheeseweasel -- `object.transactions.joins(:type).where('types.group_id' => id)`

Comment: Excellent, glad you got it sorted!